Derivation of the Marginal Likelihood for Gaussian Processes
In this post a derivation of the marginal likelihood for Gaussian process regression is given. This is the most detailed derivation of the marginal likelihood for GPR I have seen so far. There are, however, two spots in the last paragraph where I stumbled:
Number 1: (solved, see below)
I am not sure what $\frac{\Sigma + K}{\Sigma K}$ is supposed to mean. The most plausible explanation for me is $(\Sigma + K)(\Sigma K)^{-1}$, but I don't see how to recover $\Sigma^{-1} + K^{-1}$ from that:
\begin{align*}
    (\Sigma + K)(\Sigma K)^{-1}
        &= (\Sigma + K) K^{-1} \Sigma^{-1}
\\[2mm]
        &= \Sigma K^{-1} \Sigma^{-1} + K K^{-1} \Sigma^{-1}
\\[2mm]
        &= \Sigma K^{-1} \Sigma^{-1} + \Sigma^{-1}
\end{align*}
But $\Sigma K^{-1} \Sigma^{-1} \ne K^{-1}$, or is this product somehow commutative?
Number 2:
When substituting $\Pi$ and $\nu$ into the exponent (as described in the post), I get:
\begin{align*}
    \nu^\intercal \Pi^{-1} \nu - y^\intercal \Sigma^{-1} y
        &= (\Pi \Sigma^{-1} y)^\intercal \Pi^{-1} (\Pi \Sigma^{-1} y)
            - y^\intercal \Sigma^{-1} y
\\[2mm]
        &= y^\intercal \Sigma^{-1} \Pi \Pi^{-1} \Pi \Sigma^{-1} y
            - y^\intercal \Sigma^{-1} y
\\[2mm]
        &= y^\intercal \Sigma^{-1} \Pi \Sigma^{-1} y
            - y^\intercal \Sigma^{-1} y
\\[2mm]
        &= y^\intercal ( \Sigma^{-1} \Pi \Sigma^{-1} - \Sigma^{-1} ) y
\\[2mm]
        &= y^\intercal ( \Sigma^{-1} (\Sigma^{-1} + K^{-1})^{-1} \Sigma^{-1}
            - \Sigma^{-1} ) y
\end{align*}
I am not quite sure how to arrive at $y^\intercal \Sigma^{-1} (\Sigma^{-1} + K^{-1})^{-1} K^{-1} y$ given in the post.
Am I missing something? Any hints are highly appreciated.
Thanks a lot in advance and best reards.

EDIT:
I was able to solve the first one (see comment). What I am still struggling with is number 2: How do I get this result when inserting the definitions of $\Pi$ and $\nu$:


I found the solution for "number 1" using the matrix identities (163) and (165) from the matrix cookbook: https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf
